# move camera with player [unity]

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class follow_mainship : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Playerposition;
    private Vector3 cameraoffset;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cameraoffset = Playerposition.position - transform.position;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newpos = Playerposition.position + cameraoffset;
    }
}
```

I am using this code to move camera with my player, but it is not working. I have added my object in the Playerposition box. What should I do?

**Update:
As per the answer, camera is following my ship, whenever the ship touches the ground, the camera flies back a long distance. Is there any way to fix it?**

Comment: you did not even move the camera in your code

Comment: You're not updating anything right now, all you are doing is setting the `cameraoffset` variable, adding the player position to it, and setting this new value to `newpos`. But you are not doing anything with `newpos`. you need to add a reference to the Camera to your variables (`Camera playerCamera;`, and set it from the inspector). Then update its position in your update using (for example) `playerCamera.transform.position = newpos;`

Answer (score 1):

Your logic to get the new position is correct, but in your Update() function, you have to update the position of the camera using transform.position, assuming this script is a component you have added to the Camera in the scene.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Vector3 newpos = Playerposition.position + cameraoffset;
    transform.position = newpos;
}
```

If this script isn't on the camera, you'll need a reference to the camera by taking it as an input in the Unity inspector (declaring `public Camera cam;` at the top of your class) and then set in in the inspector by dragging the camera object onto that input. Then you can do `cam.transform.position = newpos;` in Update().